# javascript changing http request to https

Tags: javascript, http-headers, fetch-api

I am fetching an API using fetch
the url of the API is in `http` but whenever I am sending the request javascript is converting it into `https`

My Javascript code is

```
form.addEventListener("submit", (el) => {
  el.preventDefault();
  const city = input.value;
  fetch(
    `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=113582164e8a6873ca56cbba32c571ee&query=${city}`,
    {
      referrerPolicy: "unsafe-url",
    }
  )
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((apiResponse) => {
      console.log(apiResponse);
    });
});
```

On Browser I am getting this error
[image]

Can anyone please help me out on how to make http request

Comment: Seems like you need to pay for a subscription plan which allows you to access the https:// URL.

Comment: but its working completely fine on http request if I make a request using node js

Comment: I would guess there's also a CORS issue happening then if the request works server side, but not client side.

Comment: it works on server side because Node js is not converting my request from http to https

Comment: even if you check http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=113582164e8a6873ca56cbba32c571ee&query=hoshiarpur

Comment: you can't call `fetch` to `http`, when the call is coming from `https`. See https://dev.to/mittalyashu/mixed-content-fetching-data-from-https-and-http-3n31 for example

Comment: My guess is that it works via **http** using node.js because node is running on the server, whereas executing client-size JavaScript uses a browser and all modern browsers attempt to force **https** on all requests.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/bGyK9yV — I can't reproduce the problem.